# Merge folders. Access denied - code 5

Tags: php

I am trying to merge two folders and I'm getting

> Access is denied. (code: 5)

I'm running Windows 7 x64 if it makes any difference.

My code is this

[image]

Both folders exist, `C:/zzampp` has a file inside. I have write permissions for both folders and none of them is being used or open in another application. Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge two directories you should rename the contents to the new destination:

```
rename('C:/zzampp/file.txt', 'C:/zampp/file.txt');
```

If you have multiple contents you can use [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) to get a list.

Comment: This sounds really ridiculous. There is literally no way to actually merge two folders without manually looping through *every* single entry?

Comment: Well sorry, but no - not within the PHP core-functions. Maybe someone else already wrote a script for this and put it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You should first copy file inside zzamp to zamp.

Then rename zzamp to zamp.

That s why you have an permission issue

A good test should to write the script in a php file, to get the exact line where permission issue occurs.

Then you should parse zzamp dir through a loop to move files inside to the new one.

Here is an example

```
 <?php

if ($handle = opendir.    ('/path/to/files')) {
echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
echo "Entries:\n";

/* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    echo "$entry\n";
}

/* This is the WRONG     way to loop over the       directory. */
while ($entry = readdir.   ($handle)) {
    echo "$entry\n";
}

closedir($handle);
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Well that is just an example, in my application I may have hundreds of files inside my folder. How can I merge them with files inside?

Comment: Like i sais , you should loop files through directory, i ll update m'y answer